# Will splitting my LAN with a lower end router bottleneck transfer speed between devices

Tags: networking, router, nas, data-transfer

I believe I know the answer but wanted to make sure as I'm not very knowledgable with networking. I have a gigabit router as my main router that's connected to a second lower end router (DGN2200v3 ADSL2+) with a data transfer rate of 300Mbps.

If I have a NAS(gigabit ethernet) that's connected to my second router and my PC that's connected to the main router (Gigabit network card). Will the data transfer speed be significantly lower compared to having the NAS connected to the main router?

[image]

Kind Regards,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because DGN2200v3 ADSL2+ router has 10/100 Ethernet interfaces. 300Mb/s througput is true for the overall performance not for 1 ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a huge distance between NAS and PC, your data transfer rate should be around 300Mbps. But as the distance between PC and NAS increases, quality of ethernet cables come into play.

Comment: FYI they are all connected via ethernet. I obviously want the 1Gbps speed between my PC and NAS

Comment: @TykiMikk , I believe you will be limited to 300mbps.